# How to change chromium-browser indicator icon?

Tags: google-chrome, icons, chromium

I tried to copy it with

```
sudo cp /home/USERNAME/Bilder/Kram/chromium-browser.svg /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/
```

to replace the indicator icon.
But it remains always the same:

[image]

The icon I have and which I want to take instead of the one in the screenshot above is:

[image]

Comment: Are you using the hicolor theme?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I didn't need to copy into a theme folder. Try this command:

```
sudo cp /home/USERNAME/Bilder/Kram/chromium-browser.svg /usr/share/icons/chromium-browser.svg
```

And it may detect it straight away. If not, press Alt+F2 and type `r` then Enter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly it did not work :(

Comment: @FrederikFeichtmeier try a restart? Are you using HiColour?

Comment: I restarted. Still the same Icon. I use Numix-Circle as an icon set. : /

Comment: @FrederikFeichtmeier that's strange. What icon pack are you using at the moment?

Comment: I'm using the Numix-Circle icon set

Comment: @FrederikFeichtmeier so instead of copying to `/hicolor` copy to `/numix` or whatever the folder is called?

Comment: I also tried this too :) I copied it almost anywhere... from .../Numix to Numix-Circle to Numix-*/apps/*someresolutionfolder* and the same to hiocolor. Actually my icon folders are now full of my white chromium svg xD Well, thanks for your effort. I think I will just stick to the normal chromium item for the indicator then. Numix changes all of my other icons ofc and that works. Plank and unity.

Comment: Really strange... I have a different theme too and that's how I edited the icons. Hmm...